# How do I properly use a range-based for loop for an std::array

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator

I can iterate through the array with a traditional for loop and a traditional for loop with iterators, but when I try to use a ranged-based for loop, I do not get the same result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> ar = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << ar[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(std::array<int, 5>::const_iterator it = ar.begin(); it != ar.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(const int& i: ar) {
        std::cout << ar[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

```
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) `for(const int& i: ar)`, `i` refers to element but not index. So

```
for(const int& i: ar) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Comment: And there's not much point using `for(const int& i: ...` here.  `for(int i: ...` is more efficient (passing by value is more efficient than passing by reference for primitive types, since it avoids an extra dereference and the copy is cheap).

Comment: @PaulSanders Does the compiler optimized out the unnecessary reference here?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Most likely, yes.  But why take the chance?  Coding the loop with a reference here is just silly.